# How to use JSON data in Angular

Tags: json, angular

I am new to angular. I want to convert this array to JSON data and want to use it in my component. I tried using some methods mentioned  in stackoverflow, but they didn't work for me.

```
projects = [
        {
            name: 'Project1',
            day1: 4.22,
            day2: 3.56,
            day3: 3,
            day4: 1,
            day5: 7.8,
        },
        {
            name: 'Project2',
            day1: 1,
            day2: 5,
            day3: 2.5,
            day4: 4,
            day5: 1.9,
        },
        {
            name: 'Project3',
            day1: 6.78,
            day2: 2.55,
            day3: 4,
            day4: 3,
            day5: 1,
        },
    ]
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to convert to JSON data? Save it as JSON file and use/import it somewhere else in your app or simply use it as object?

Comment: Can u create stackblitz how to use data? U can use this object in your component. What do u want to change

Comment: There is no such thing as a Json data in Javascript. There are objects and arrays. What you have here is already an array of objects. You don't need any conversions. Loop through them using `*ngFor` directive and access the properties directly.

Comment: to use this array of json in .html file use ngFor and to use in .ts file use for loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print the json array values in a list using \*ngFor in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578427/how-to-print-the-json-array-values-in-a-list-using-ngfor-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want??? If you Want to stringify it then try like this.....

`var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);`

Answer (score 0):

Json arrays are already javascript arrays.
You can simply create a property in an angular component and use it in a template, perhaps with `*ngFor`, since it is an array in this case.

Your component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  projects = [
    { name: 'Project1', day1: 4.22, day2: 3.56, day3: 3, day4: 1, day5: 7.8, },
    { name: 'Project2', day1: 1, day2: 5, day3: 2.5, day4: 4, day5: 1.9, },
    { name: 'Project3', day1: 6.78, day2: 2.55, day3: 4, day4: 3, day5: 1, }
    ];
}
```

Your template:

```
<p *ngFor="let project of projects">
    {{ project.name }} | {{project.day1}} | {{project.day2}} | {{project.day2}}
</p>
```

[Angular snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pnanmn?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply manipulate/use the array as object, you do not need to convert or save to JSON. You can access and us it simply as the following in your component:

```
const projects = [
        {
            name: 'Project1',
            day1: 4.22,
            day2: 3.56,
            day3: 3,
            day4: 1,
            day5: 7.8,
        },
        {
            name: 'Project2',
            day1: 1,
            day2: 5,
            day3: 2.5,
            day4: 4,
            day5: 1.9,
        },
        {
            name: 'Project3',
            day1: 6.78,
            day2: 2.55,
            day3: 4,
            day4: 3,
            day5: 1,
        },
    ]

 projects.map(p => console.log('Current project: ', p.name));
```